# barplot R specify a tick for no observation

Tags: r, bar-chart

How can I specify a tick using `barplot` in R if that tick has no observations. So suppose I have a column in a data frame like this:

`> dat$question1
 [1] 4 3 3 5 5 4 3 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 4 5 2 4 5 4 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 4 5 5 5`

And then I plot this using

`> barplot(answers1 , main= "Answers to Question 1", ylim = c(0,30) , xlim = c(1,5))`

I get no tick in the graph for the value of 1 because it was not present in the column however it was a possibility that I need to take into account. How can I add the option to add a tick for 1 in my barplot?

Thanks for any insight.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert your variable as a factor and add levels for the absent values. For example :

```
x <- c(4, 3, 3, 5, 5, 4, 3, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 4, 5, 2, 4, 5, 4, 5, 5)
x <- factor(x, levels=1:5)
barplot(table(x))
```

[image]

Comment: very nice. Thank you.